# onKeyDown doesn't respond in TabActivity

Tags: android

My NavActivity implements TabActivity and has five child tabs. I wanna show a alert dialog when customer press back button on device. But as the title sad, it's alway not responding at this situation.

Comment: can you post some code on how are you checking the response?

Comment: do you mean "back" button on device (like "home", "options menu") or the one on you've added to your layout?

Answer (score 1):

Title says "onKeyDown", but you don't need it to catch click on "back" button. Simply override `onBackPressed()` method of your activity, something like this:

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed(){
    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Proceed with back pressed?")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ...
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .create();
    ad.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onKeyDown method of child activity is called.In order to call the onKeyDown of the TabActity just call the super onKeyDown in the child activity by 
return this.getParent().onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

Here is the code for you:
In Child Activity:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return this.getParent().onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

In your TabActivity something like this :

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        if(currenttab==0)
                 {
                    Log.e("current tab if", tabHost.getCurrentTab()+"");
        finish();
         }
         else
                 {

                  Log.e("current tab else",tabHost.getCurrentTab()+"");
          tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
          return true; //Make sure to call return true else the onkeyDown event will be propogated to the parent method.
          }
    }
    return false;
}
```